# How can I seperate square brackets content into seperate column using sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geojson

Help me convert this single column [[-101,32],[-105,36],[-107,38]]

| Column A |
| --- |
| [[-101,32],[-105,36],[-107,38]] |

into below column where each pair refers to a row.

| Column A |
| --- |
| -101,32 |
| -105,36 |
| -107,38 |

I am new to SQL so I am unable to separate these contents, someone please tell me how can I split them.

Comment: Hi - try looking at the SPLIT_TO_TABLE function

Comment: Snowflake or MySQL? these are two different DBMSs with different built-in function sets.

Comment: i was using snowflake

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code ...

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('[[-101,32],[-105,36],[-107,38]]','],[',']@['),'[',''),']',''), '@')
```